# Small images loading on Safari

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I am having problem with a images that load in very small format on http://goo.gl/ZkLIIO.
I have tested it on every browser on Windows and i dont see the problem, but i have been told that on Safari on Mac it looks very weird (aka the images get very very small).
I took a look at CSS, and i cant find any problems.

Maybe this is weird question, but can somebody take a look and let me know is this happening on your end too?

Thank you

Comment: Looks fine to me on Safari 6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a mac and the web page isn't behaving consistently. Sometimes the images look like I imagine they're supposed to, and sometimes they're, as you said, extremely tiny.

Maybe try putting your JS at the bottom of the page instead? Maybe the page and the effects and your code are loading out of sequence?

In general, it seems kind of unresponsive. If I try resizing the window, the images get stuck at certain sizes, don't go back to the way they were before, etc.

I don't have enough reputation points to post screenshots; sorry!

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Yea, i did placed the JS on the bottom, but it looks that didnt help.The worst thing is that i cant inspect the code and could see whats the problem :\

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they look small in Safari on Mac

try to check why press-gallery-item has computed width: 80px; (Use object inspector)
I will try to look deeper.

Comment: Generally, it's a good practice to define precise sizes for the smallest containers, in your case, list items "press-gallery-item".

Try to provide them fixed width and height and then the bigger containers will stretch accordingly.